# Asynchronous call to multiple APIs using NodeJS irrespective of each's result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to call multiple endpoints using NodeJS and it is giving result, but the problem is that it gives a result after all requests have got 200 or some valid HTTP response. What I wanted to do is get all results irrespective of other API. 
E.g If I am calling 3 Endpoints viz. A, B, C. If endpoint B is delaying response because of server issues my code shouldn't wait for B to complete the request and send response of other completed requests.

I am using Async Promise but it is not giving out desired output. It prints all the result when the slowest API's request gets completed.

```
const request = require('request');

var requestAsync = function(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = request(url, (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) return reject(err, response, body);
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });
    });
};

const urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    'http://localhost/local/node/1.php',
];


var getParallel = async function() {
    //transform requests into Promises, await all
    try {
        var data = await Promise.all(urls.map(requestAsync));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
}

getParallel();
```

Comment: if you know the length of array in advance, you could try `// this calls in parallel
var results = urls.map(requestAsync);
var data1 = results[0].then(d => // do something).catch()` etc.. (You could try for loop, never tried tho)

Comment: I don't think `await` is good for what you're trying to achieve, unless (luckily) you do `await call()` as the last call, you're going to have to wait till the await resolves

Comment: This sounds good, I will try and get back to you. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.race` to ensure that the returned Promise will resolve (or reject) after no more than a specified period of time. For example, the below will ensure that the `Promise.all` will either resolve or reject after 3000 ms:

```
var requestAsync = function(url) {
    return Promise.race([
        new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'too slow')),
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var req = request(url, (err, response, body) => {
                if (err) return reject(err, response, body);
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            });
        })
    ]);
};
```

If you want to reject if any are taking too long, simply pass `reject` into the `setTimeout` instead of `resolve` (where `reject` is the second parameter to the `new Promise` callback).

Comment: or `var data = await Promise.race(urls.map(requestAsync));`

Comment: That would only ever wait for a single result, though.

Comment: opps, sorry misread! didn't notice `get all results irrespective of other API`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But after 3 seconds of waiting my delayed request is not giving me any response at all. It prints too slow and then stops but other response gets printed. Am I missing something here? I have put one of my local api in url list which I throttled and gives delayed response after 30 seconds.

Comment: @GaneshSawant I can't reproduce your problem - looks to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9fgkd416/

Comment: Actually, I don't want to reject after some short specified time. I will stop polling server after 2 minutes of no response. but till that time all resolved request should come. Here, everything stops for specified time and when times-up all response came at one go.

Comment: @GaneshSawant Feel free to change the `setTimeout` time to whatever you want - if you want to force a resolve after 2 minutes, then use `120000` (2 minutes) instead of `3000` (3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `await` (or `Promise.all`) is good for what you're trying to achieve, unless (luckily) you do await call() as the last call, you're going to have to wait till the `await` resolves (or all promise is resolved or rejected).

Say you have `giveSome()` which does some asynchronous work and returns a `Promise`. Say you have task `A` and `B`. A completes after 5s and B completes after 1s. Now you do

```
// called in parallel
// both a and b are promise pending
var a = giveSome() // task A
var b = giveSome() // task B

// do something with data in async function
console.log(await a) // this is resolved only after 5s
console.log(await b) // this is already resolved after 1s but waits for the await above
```

Instead if you do:

```
a.then(val => console.log(val)) // outputs val after 5s
b.then(val => console.log(val)) // outputs val after 1s
```

So in your case you could:

```
var data = urls.map(requestAsync);

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i]
    .then(val => console.log(val) // do something)
    // burden is you need to handle errors individually
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to call a method `x` after each response. Instead of doing `Promise.all` on request call, you can create another Promise to do your work. Wrap each request in an individual `Promise`, which will do your job, and then use another `Promise.all` just to check if execution is done for all. Here is an example code -

```
let promises = [];

urls.forEach(url => {
  promise.push(requestAsync(url)
    .then(x)  // Replace `x`
    .catch(console.error)  // Silently dropping error
  )
})

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
     console.log("All Executed", {results});  // Result will be response from `x` method
  })
  .catch(console.error); // If method `x` throws an error, it will go to this catch
```